# How to find element in set (not check existence) in Python? Does Python set have a corresponding function of C++'s std::unordered_set::find?

Tags: python

Typical case:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.age == other.age

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.age)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Person {}>'.format(self.name)

v1 = Person('tom', 18)
v2 = Person('mary', 22)
v3 = Person('mary2', 22)

person_set = {v1, v2, v3}
print(person_set)
```

Now I only knows the age of the element I want to find is 18. How to find its name? Etc how to get the a reference to the element "Person('tom', 18)" in the hash set?

I want to do this job in **O(1)** (C++'s std::unordered_set::find can do. Basically, construct a object with any name Person('xxx', 18) and call  std::unordered_set::find. C# added a similar function HashSet.TryGetValue(T, T) at very recent version 4.7.2)

**For python, I understanding using dictionary can be a workaround. But I want to know if there is a direct solution, similar to C++'s std::unordered_set::find?.**

***I need O(1) solution instead of O(N) solution. Otherwise, hash set makes no sense.***

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to do. How do you expect to find the element if you don't have it already? If you already have it, why do you want to find it still?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, Thanks. Just update. "I want to find element, tom, in the set. And change its name to another name of the item in the hash set. I want to do this job in O(1)"

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, Thanks. C++ is O(1). So far python set cannot job it in O(1)

Comment: I am afraid that does not answer my question at all. What operation do you expect to perform? Do you expect something akin to ``tom = magic(person_set, name='tom')`` or ``tom = magic(person_set, tom)``? [C++ ``std::unordered_set::find``](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) finds *a given element* in a set – it is equivalent to Python ``tom in person_set`` – which means you must already have said element. This seems completely unrelated to your described task of changing the name of the element, since you can directly change the name if you have said element..

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, some one reminds me that key in python is immutable. So I've updated my prescription "How to find out the name of the element "Person('tom', 18)"?"

Comment: That still seems a bit vague. The name of the element ``Person('tom', 18)`` is ``Person('tom', 18).name``, which has nothing to do with``person_set``. Are you wondering how to find the name of the person in ``person_set`` whose age is 18? Since you are looking for a lookup from some feature to a separate value, why do you consider using a ``dict`` *a workaround*? That is practically what ``dict`` exists for.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, Thanks. Update again "Now I only knows the age of the element I want to find is 18. How to find its name? Etc how to get the a reference to the element "Person('tom', 18)" in the hash set?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to do this in O(1). `set` is not intended for such operations, and will not consistently return a search element versus a contained element. The closest operation is [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.intersection), which uses arbitrary order and may thus return either the search or result element.

```
class HashKV:
    """A key: value pair with hash/eq defined by key, similar to a ``dict`` pair"""
    def __init__(self, k, v): self.k, self.v = k, v
    def __hash__(self): return hash(self.k)
    def __eq__(self, other): return self.k == other.k
    def __repr__(self): return f'{self.k}: {self.v}'

# Search Key - value is a placeholder
search = {HashKV(1, '?')}
# Search First - Works
print(search & {HashKV(1, 1)})  # {1: 1}
# Search Last - Fails
print({HashKV(1, 1)} & search)  # {1: ?}
# Search First - Fails
print(search & {HashKV(1, 1), HashKV(2, 2)})  # {1: ?}
# Search Last - Fails
print({HashKV(1, 1), HashKV(2, 2)} & search)  # {1: ?}
```

At least in CPython, [set intersection returns elements from the shorter set](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/setobject.c#L1201-L1221), i.e. the search set and not the searched set.

The appropriate data structure to map from a key to a value is `dict`.

```
>>> v1 = Person('tom', 18)
>>> v2 = Person('mary', 22)
>>> v3 = Person('mary2', 22)
>>> person_map = {v.age: v for v in (v1, v2, v3)}
>>> person_map[18].name
tom
>>> person_map[18].name = 'barry'
>>> person_map[18].name
barry
```

Comment: Thanks. Set intersection seems most close solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in person_set:
   if item.name == 'tom':
       item.name = 'another name'
       break
```

Comment: Thanks. I need O(1) solution of O(N). Otherwise, hash set makes no sense.

Comment: Well, then no, don't use `set`, use a `dict` with names as keys.

Answer (score 0):

There's no direct equivalent because **to quickly retrieve a specific element, you need to already know it** -- to be able to calculate its hash code -- so you already have it, just check membership if you want to know if it's present. Neither is there sense to return an "iterator to it" which is what the C++ function does -- because the set is unordered, the notion of a position in it is meaningless. Finally, because C++ has manual memory management and everything is mutable in it, you may want to use that iterator to retrieve the stored object instead of an equivalent one that you've constucted -- this doesn't apply to Python, either.

---

To alter a stored element, since they need to be immutable, you need to delete the old one and insert a new one:

```
tom = Person('tom', 18)   # if you know the element exactly

person_set.remove(tom)
person_set.add(Person('tom', 18))
```

If you don't know the element exactly, your only option is to search all elements one by one using the usual (i.e. not set-specific) syntax like in a list by whatever criteria -- which will have *O(N)* complexity. Note that this may yield any number of results, including none.

```
[e for e in person_set if e.name == 'tom']
```

Comment: Your first sentence seems misleading. Actually, IIUC, `set::unordered_set::find` also requires knowing the element. And unless the data structure has some kind of hashed index of the name field, there is no way to do better than O(N) anyway.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut updated. AFAICS, the only meaningful use for C++ function is an awkward way to check membership with `s.find(element) == s.end()`. Python does away with that awkwardness and just returns the bool directly.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Oh, I forgot that in C++, everything is mutable -- so it does make sense to be able to retrieve the contained object instead of an equal one. But in Python, hash keys need to be immutable, so it makes no difference if you have the same object or an equivalent one.

Comment: Yes. I meant: both Python and C++ need to know the element to find it, there is no magical "quickly find by name" in a data structure that is not indexed by name (or sorted, or whatever). It may be different if all the fields are known, good point.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev, thanks. Just update description "How to find out the name of the element "Person('tom', 18)"?"

Comment: There is no need to remove-and-add the element in this case. Mutability is only relevant for the data used in hash/eq, and ``Person`` does not use ``name`` for hash/eq.